# Pre-populating Local SSD disk in GCP Kubernetes for readonly multipods usage

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

What is the best way to preload large files into a local PersistentVolume SSD before it gets used by Kubernetes pods?

The goal is to have multiple pods (could be multiple instances of the same pod, or different), share the same local SSD drive in a read-only mode. The drive would need to be initialized somehow with a large dataset.

Google [Local SSD docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd) describes the `Running the local volume static provisioner`, but that approach only creates a PersistedVolume, but does not initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can add an `init` container to your pod that initializes the SSD: add data, etc.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "test-ssd"
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: "init"
    image: "ubuntu:14.04"
    command: ["/bin/init_my_ssd.ssh"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/test-ssd/"
      name: "test-ssd:
  containers:
  - name: "shell"
    image: "ubuntu:14.04"
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: ["echo 'hello world' > /test-ssd/test.txt && sleep 1 && cat /test-ssd/test.txt"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/test-ssd/"
      name: "test-ssd"
  volumes:
  - name: "test-ssd"
    hostPath:
      path: "/mnt/disks/ssd0"
  nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/gke-local-ssd: "true"
```

Comment: your answer uses `hostPath` approach, which is not very flexible (per docs link in the question) - i was hoping to use auto-provisioned volumes. Also, would `initContainers` section be more appropriate, as it will exit once the volume is initialized?

Comment: Yes, you can use initContainers. I’ve changed the answer. As far as the hostpath I suppose u need it since it’s local. You mean flexibility like an elastic volume?

Comment: Rico, no, I meant that multiple pods may use different local SSDs, and hostPath always uses hardcoded one. The docs link in the question describes how to set up a service to auto-create them.

Comment: @Yurik the `hostPath` is actually on the machine and all the pods run on the machine. What you care about in the container is the `mountPath`. Makes sense?

Comment: of course, but if have 10 local ssds, and you run multiple versions of your code on the same node, each pod should use its own local ssd.  Pods shouldn't know if the hostPath is ssd0 or ssd5.  It should simply ask for a local ssd.

Comment: `/mnt/disks/ssd0` can be anything and it could be the same for all your nodes. It could be something like `/mnt/disks/myonlyssdonthisnode`

Comment: the goal is not to have it the same for all nodes. If i have two different versions of a pod on the same node, they should use different hostpath, but it could be different between nodes (e.g.if node only has newer pod).  According to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd - `All the local SSDs have to be accessed at the same path across all instances of a DaemonSet.` This is not a very flexible approach from my understanding, that's why they offer LPV path -- so that pods don't have to hardcode the path to the disk.